# How to deploy a spring boot app in google cloud?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a Java Spring Boot app to Google Cloud and I have some problems.
I tried two methods:

1. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart
2. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-google-app-engine

This is the error i get with the first deployment method (gcloud app deploy):

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (KeyError): None
```

This is the error i get with the second deployment method (maven deploy):

```
Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project server: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1
```

I feel like I missed some deployment step - i don't know which though.
What I'm doing is:

1. Create project from console.cloud.google.com.
2. Open Google SDK Shell.
3. Go to folder.
4. 'google init' to select the project and user.
5. 'google app create'.
6. 'google app deploy' / deploy from maven with 'mvn clean package appengine:deploy -P cloud-gcp' or 'mvn clean -DskipTests appengine:deploy'.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>server</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server</name>
    <description>Description</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <servlet.version>4.0.0</servlet.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.60</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.humble/humble-video-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.humble</groupId>
            <artifactId>humble-video-all</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
*db config*

spring.cloud.appId=*id*

spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=*copied name from cloud*
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=*db name*
```

appengine/app.yaml

```
runtime: java11
env: flex
env_variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp,mysql"
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

^ also tried only with:

```
runtime: java11
```

webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java11</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

EDIT:
Running the maven deploy with the flag '-e' gave the following trace:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project server: Execution default-cli of goal com.g
oogle.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit (NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:28)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.syncRun (DefaultProcessRunner.java:209)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.run (DefaultProcessRunner.java:137)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runGcloudCommand (CloudSdk.java:179)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runAppCommandInWorkingDirectory (CloudSdk.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.deploy (CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a xml and a yaml? We use the `standard` env with java11 and `app.yaml`. Note that you could also use Google Cloud Run. Also check of you have the latest cloudsdk version and try `gcloud feedback`.

Comment: Removed the xml file and added the 'env: standard' attribute. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of challenges:

1. The GCP standard environment provides Jetty instead of Tomcat
2. Google has fixed the `app.yaml` / `appengine-web.xml` issues in later versions of the plug-in

```xml
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
```

and at the end of your `<dependencyManagement/>` import:

```xml
      <!-- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

and take advantage of the updated versions in your `<dependencies/>` accordingly.

I suggest you package your application in a separate JAR and include the dependency in your `pom.xml` like:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>GROUP</groupId>
      <artifactId>ARTIFACT</artifactId>
      <version>VERSION</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Where GROUP:ARTIFACT:VERSION are your application JAR's actual Maven coordinates.

In the `WEB-INF` folder, add your `appengine-web.xml` (something like):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>GROUP</application>
  <service>ARTIFACT</service>
  <version>VERSION</version>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <basic-scaling>
    <max-instances>1</max-instances>
    <idle-timeout>5m</idle-timeout>
  </basic-scaling>
  <instance-class>B1</instance-class>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
  <env-variables>
    <env-var name="SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE" value="gcp,mysql"/>
  </env-variables>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Where GROUP, ARTIFACT, and VERSION correspond to your JAR's Maven artifact groupId, artifactId, and version, respectively.

Once I updated the plug-in, I found I no longer needed to have an `app.yaml` file.  You'll need to include a `logging.properties`:

```
# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = WARNING
```

Finally, re-package your GROUP:ARTIFACT:VERSION jar in your POM (note that `${start-class}` must be defined for your application):

```xml
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <profiles>
            <profile>gcp</profile>
            <profile>mysql</profile>
          </profiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Use `mvn clean package appengine:deploy` to deploy.  This [article](https://blog.hcf.dev/article/2018-12-18-gae-deployment-experience/) has more details.